# concat two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ISS.fdIssuerId as ID
,rpad(concat(ISS.fdIssuerName, '-', ISS.fdType),20,' ') as Symbol
,concat(LPAD('Group-',10,' '), ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, '')) as groups
,concat(rpad(concat(ISS.fdIssuerName, '-', ISS.fdType),20,' 
'),concat(LPAD('Group-',10,' '), ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, ''))) as asdf
FROM tbissuer ISS
LEFT JOIN tbgroupissuermapping IGM ON IGM.fdIssuerId = ISS.fdIssuerId
LEFT JOIN tbgroup GRP ON GRP.fdGroupId = IGM.fdGroupId
Order by  Symbol asc;
```

this command gives me the result like as picture [Show picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ZKD.png)

but i want to concate 'symbol' and 'group' column as i did in third column named 'asdf', but it gives me scattered records as you see, i want to align keyword 'group' equally in result.

Answer (score 0):

could be that instead  of fixed  20 char il rpad
you need 20 - length(concat(LPAD('Group-',10,' '), ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, '')))

```
SELECT ISS.fdIssuerId as ID
      ,rpad(concat(ISS.fdIssuerName, '-', ISS.fdType),20,' ') as Symbol
      ,concat(LPAD('Group-',10,' '), ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, '')) as groups
      ,concat(rpad(concat(ISS.fdIssuerName, '-', ISS.fdType),
         20- length(concat(LPAD('Group-',10,' '), ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, ''))),' ') 
            ,concat(LPAD('Group-',10,' '), ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, ''))) as asdf
  FROM tbissuer ISS
  LEFT JOIN tbgroupissuermapping IGM ON IGM.fdIssuerId = ISS.fdIssuerId
  LEFT JOIN tbgroup GRP ON GRP.fdGroupId = IGM.fdGroupId
  Order by  Symbol asc;
```

Comment: and i used space(N) method, which provide space between strings, but didnot work

Comment: and i used space(N) method, which provide space between strings, but didnot work

Comment: select * from"
                + " ( SELECT ISS.fdIssuerId as liValueMember, CONCAT(concat(ISS.fdIssuerName, '-', ISS.fdType),space(120-length(concat(ISS.fdIssuerName, '-', ISS.fdType))- length(concat('Group-', ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, '--')))),concat('Group-', ifnull(GRP.fdgroupName, '--'))) as lsDisplayMember, 0 as orderby FROM tbissuer ISS"
                + " LEFT JOIN tbgroupissuermapping IGM ON IGM.fdIssuerId = ISS.fdIssuerId"
                + " LEFT JOIN tbgroup GRP ON GRP.fdGroupId = IGM.fdGroupId where ISS.fdstatus = 1) x Order by orderby desc, lsDisplayMember asc;

Comment: what do you mean with "didnot work "  ?  . you have error? show th error message ..wrong result ?  showe you actual result and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

please see my actual result in link

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDvCo.png)

and my expected result should be like this

`20MICRONS-EQ    Group-AA
3IINFOTECH-EQ    Group-AA
3MINDIA-EQ       Group-AA
5PAISA-EQ        Group-A3
63MOONS-EQ       Group-A3
8KMILES-EQ       Group-
A2ZINFRA-EQ      Group-`